# inserting header axios async thunk

Tags: javascript, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm trying to set apikey in the header of req-- it gives me Cors error when done locally,
though when done on postman it goes through

```js
export const fetchCreativeAd = createAsyncThunk(
  'creativeAd/fetchCreativeAd',
  async (payload, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const urlParam = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_ENDPOINT;
      const response = await axios.get(
        `${urlParam}/creative_ad?product_name=${payload.productName}&product_description=${payload.productDescription}&platform=${payload.platform}&audience=${payload.audience}&ad_tone=${payload.adTone}`,
        {
          headers: {
            'x-api-key': `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_API_KEY}`,
          },
        }
      );
      res.data.headers['x-api-key'];
      console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AWS_API_KEY);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error: error.message });
    }
  }
);
```

Cors error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at '"urlParam"creative_ad?product_name=asdf&product_description=asdf&platform=asdf&audience=asdf&ad_tone=asdf' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

how do I insert the header portion in axios?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? You can't fix CORS errors from the client side but if you control the API service, you should be able to enable access

Comment: @Phil updated -- I had also enabled cors on aws as well as the the endpoints I created. It works without the apikey implementation

Comment: Adding the header makes the request non-simple and requires a pre-flight `OPTIONS` request. What sort of AWS service is it?

Comment: @Phil aws api gateway-- I created the endpoints through fastapi where I'm also allowing all cors origins, headers, credentials, etc through the middleware

Comment: API gateway has it's own set of [CORS configurations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html)

Comment: @Phil yes, I had already enabled cors on AWS and the options method is already checked

Comment: @temrb If you don't see an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the *response* it won't work. The browser refuses to talk to such an endpoint.